# Set page background without referring to <body>

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and web design so please be gentle ;-)

I was wondering if it is possible to define the background of a page (i.e. what color the screen is) without referring to the  tag. So not doing the typical:

```
body { background-color: #fff; }
```

I need to do this since I am writing css to stylize our login page, but only have access to the template html to be inserted into the page body. So my html looks something like this (very simplified):

```
<div id="loginpage"> 
  <div id="title"/>
  <div id="content"/>
</div>
```

I couldn't find any answers online since this seems to be an unusual way of doing it. 
So: Is this possible, if yes - how?

Comment: you can use div id to specify the background-color(if you are not willing to use body tag).

Comment: What do you mean by "without referring to the tag"?

Comment: I meant not styling the 'body' in the css, as in the example..

Comment: The question is not clear at all. What are the mystical requirements of styling the body without styling the body? You could always style the `html` element of course if you expect the `body` element background be not set (i.e. default to transparent).

Comment: I am styling the page, and was asked to only include css referring to elements that are actually in the html page I'm using (see above). Since the `html` and `body` elements are not part of this section of html page, I am asking for a way to set the background color without referring to these.

Comment: I do realise this is an unusual way to proceed, but am positive there are solutions out there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Aroot#Browser_compatibility) selector if you don't mind about losing IE6-8 support.

But have you tried targeting `body` or `html`, in spite of the fact that they're not in the code? They still get inserted into the DOM.

Comment: +1 Or rather, they are still there when the template is inserted :)

Comment: I did do that first (just target `body`) , but was friendly reminded by my team members to only style elements that are actually on the page I am working on... (which is not the case for `body`).

Comment: When I say that they're inserted into the DOM, I really do mean it. They do by definition. If you include head elements you can't trust old versions of IE, but old browsers consistently inserted html/head and so in HTML5 where the parser was rigidly specified it covers precisely how it should handle things like "missing html element" and "missing body element": see the "anything else" sections in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tree-construction.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tree-construction.html#the-after-head-insertion-mode

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #999;">&nbsp;</div>
```

(put it above all your other html, and maybe use `z-index: 1;` if necessary)

Comment: Eak! (This is a very nasty idea, as well as not necessary!)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you need to discuss this with your team members and a superior. If you find a work around you may come to work tomorrow and find that someone has added

```
body { 
  background-color: #not-white !important;
}
```

after your code and your next question is how to override `!important` in css.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, whoever made the restriction of not giving you access to css/main template should *really* not do that. If you continue working like that you'd end up with a lot of workarounds that will likely bite you.

Regardless of the restiction you could add a style tag like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-color:#fff;}
</style>
```

which would take priority over the original body rule (assuming the body flow is not tampered with). This would be safer than setting background colour for `*` which would have unexpected side-effects. You may also want to set it through the shorthand `background:#fff;` which will reset any background image etc. previosly applied.

### Update

I've just seen your comment

> I did do that first (just target body) , but was friendly reminded by
>   my team members to only style elements that are actually on the page I
>   am working on... (which is not the case for body).

Assuming it's a valid argument and not some sort of petty tyranny going on, maybe it could be appropriate setting the background on the loginpage element? You could reference elements by ID like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
#loginpage {background-color:#fff;}
</style>
```

Comment: the loginpage element has a different color, it is the actual login 'box' in the middle of the page. using this approach, I would need an additional `<div>` around #loginpage (similar to @Teak answer), which I would like to avoid...

Comment: @FSchmidt: do go with the body rule then. There's no reason not to - the logic with the original approach above is pretty straightforward: "if I am on a login page and only then, set body background to white" which is *exactly* what you're after!